# PowerShell 51 function not displaying expected ouput

Tags: powershell

I'm testing deserializing and splatting but not getting expected output from function `Function1`

**Deserializing (not working as expected)**

```
$pick1 = 'red,blue' -split ","
$favoriteColors = @()
$favoriteColors += $pick1

$payload = @{}
$payload.add('DEV',@{firstName='Rod';favoriteColors=$favoriteColors})

# Serialize 
$serialPayload = $payload | ConvertTo-Json -compress

# Deserialize test
$payload2 = @{}
(ConvertFrom-Json $serialPayload).psobject.properties | Foreach { $payload2[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

function Main(){
  $test = $payload2['DEV']
  Function1 @test
}
function Function1([object] $favoriteColors){
  "Value1: $($favoriteColors)"
}

Main
```

I was expecting:

```
"red,blue" string
```

But I'm getting the entire `payload2['DEV']` object, not what I expected from splatting.

```
Value1: @{favoriteColors=System.Object[]; firstName=Rod}
```

**Without serializing (works as expected)**

```
$pick1 = 'red,blue' -split ","
$favoriteColors = @()
$favoriteColors += $pick1

$payload = @{}
$payload.add('DEV',@{firstName='Rod';favoriteColors=$favoriteColors})

function Main(){

  $test = $payload['DEV']
  Function1 @test
}
function Function1([object] $favoriteColors){
  "Value: $($favoriteColors)"
}

Main
```

Output:

```
Value: red blue
```

Comment: Yes this is expected, Json will be deserialized as PSCustomObjects not as Hashtables. If you want to preserve the types you can use CliXml, in either case, your splatting doesn't make any sense with or without serialization

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I updated with serializing/deserializing (not working) and non serializing (working) examples

Comment: Now your code is making sense and the question is valid but my comment still stands, Json objects are deserialized as PSCustomObject not as hashtables so you need to convert the value of the `DEV` property into a hashtable

Comment: The value of the `DEV` property: `...psobject.properties.Value` <- you need to access `.psobject.properties` of it and create a new hashtable out it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reserialize then deserialize, feedback?

```
$pick1 = 'red,blue' -split ","
$favoriteColors = @()
$favoriteColors += $pick1

$pick2 = 'green,yellow' -split ","
$favoriteColors2 = @()
$favoriteColors2 += $pick2

$payload = @{}
$payload.add('DEV',@{firstName='Rod';favoriteColors=$favoriteColors})
$payload.add('UAT',@{firstName='Char';favoriteColors=$favoriteColors2})

# Serialize 
$serialPayload = $payload | ConvertTo-Json -compress

# Deserialize test
$payload2 = @{}
(ConvertFrom-Json $serialPayload).psobject.properties.Value.psobject.Properties | Foreach { $payload2[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

function Main(){

  Function1 @payload2
}
function Function1([object] $favoriteColors){
  "Value1: $($favoriteColors)"
}

Main
```

Comment: what I meant was `(ConvertFrom-Json $serialPayload).psobject.properties.Value.psobject.Properties | Foreach { $payload2[$_.Name] = $_.Value }` no need for 2 hashtables then from `Main` you can just do `Function1 @payload2`

Comment: ok, updated and i added another item to collection DEV and UAT how do I select one or both to use

Comment: now the answer is to enumerated each object and create a hashtable per each property `DEV` and `UAT` tho thats unrelated to the initial question and the answer section is specifically for answers